# Connecting to EC2 instances using the instance name instead of IP

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services

I'm an intensive user of AWS EC2 instances, many instances are launched, stopped, repurposed, etc.

To connect to any instance using `SSH` I must keep track of their IPs.

The bash script I wrote (following the [question I asked on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21424849/is-there-an-easy-way-to-connect-to-ec2-instances-using-their-name-tag)) uses `aws-cli` to do the heavy lifting for me, leaving me to remember only the logical names I've given to my instances.

Here is the main code, including the auto-completion code:

```
# connect to machine
function sash {
  if [ -z $1 ]; then
    echo "Please enter machine name"
    return 1
  fi
  local instance ip pem
  instance=$(aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=tag:Name,Values=$1" "Name=instance-state-name,Values=running" --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[].[KeyName,PublicIpAddress]' --output text)

  if [ -z "${instance}" ]; then
    echo Could not find an instance named $1
    return 1
  else
    ip=$(echo $instance | awk '{print $2}')
    pem=$(echo $instance | awk '{print $1}')

    echo "Connecting to $1 ($ip)"
    ssh -i ~/.aws/$pem.pem ubuntu@$ip
  fi
}

function clear_sash {
  unset -v _sash_instances
}

# completion command
function _sash {
  if [ -z "${_sash_instances}" ]; then
    _sash_instances="$( aws ec2 describe-tags --filter Name=key,Values=Name Name=resource-type,Values=instance --query Tags[].Value --output text )"
  fi

  local curw
  COMPREPLY=()
  curw=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}
  COMPREPLY=($(compgen -W "${_sash_instances}" -- $curw))
  return 0
}

complete -F _sash sash
```

The main function (`sash`) takes the first parameter, and queries `aws ec2` for a machine with a 'Name' tag with that value, extracts its public ip and `pem` file, and calls the proper `ssh` command.

The auto-completion command (`_sash`) enumerates the names of all EC2 machines, and keeps them in a cache in the scope of the shell.

A small helper command (`clear_sash`) is used to clear the cache for the auto-complete.

Since this is the first function I've written in bash, I would love to hear some opinions on the code, style, caching decisions, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's mostly fine, but I would suggest some minor improvements.

Give a proper name to `$1` early on, for example:

```
host=$1
if [ -z $host ]; then
  echo "Please enter machine name"
  return 1
fi
```

You use it in several places later and it will make the code more readable.

---

Instead of this:

```
if [ -z "${instance}" ]; then
```

you can use `[[ ... ]]` instead and drop the double quotes:

```
if [[ -z $instance ]]; then
```

---

This is a bit ugly:

> ```
> ip=$(echo $instance | awk '{print $2}')
> pem=$(echo $instance | awk '{print $1}')
> ```

It's ugly because you're spawning two `awk` processes for the same input. You could use a single `read` instead:

```
read pem ip junk <<< $instance
```

Or perhaps slightly cleaner to read into an array:

```
read -a arr <<< $instance
ip=${arr[1]}
pem=${arr[0]}
```

The array solution is especially good if the indexes of ip and pem are dynamic, for example if they come from variables:

```
read -a arr <<< $instance
# given: ip_idx=2 and pem_idx=1
ip=${arr[$ip_idx - 1]}
pem=${arr[$pem_idx - 1]}
```

(It would be cleaner to have the `*_idx` 0-based, but I used this example for the sake of illustrating simple arithmetics in array indexes.)

For the record, here's my earlier uglier `awk` solution:

```
set -- $(awk '{print $1, $2}' <<< $instance)
pem=$1
ip=$2
```

This is not as good as `read`, because it spawns an `awk` process, and it overwrites the positional parameters `$1`, `$2`, ... Other variants using `$pem_idx` and `$ip_idx`:

```
set -- $(awk "{print \$$pem_idx, \$$ip_idx}" <<< $instance)
# or:
set -- $(awk -v ip_idx=$ip_idx -v pem_idx=$pem_idx '{print $(pem_idx), $(ip_idx)}' <<< $instance)
```

---

In this code:

> ```
> local curw
> COMPREPLY=()
> curw=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}
> COMPREPLY=($(compgen -W "${_sash_instances}" -- $curw))
> ```

The first `COMPREPLY=()` is unnecessary because you overwrite it soon after anyway.

Also, I think it's better to write `local` on the same line as the assignment:

```
local curw=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}
```

Actually, since the line fits within 80 characters, I'm not sure I would use the local `curw` at all:

```
COMPREPLY=($(compgen -W "${_sash_instances}" -- ${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}))
```

---

The final `return 0` is unnecessary if the last operation is successful. If the last operation is not successful, you probably want to let the function return failure anyway.